# Play music through multiple speakers

Tags: audio, speakers, multiple

Hi I'm working on a project where I'd like to hook up about 15 small speakers and play music through them.

I'm setting up a haunted path for a halloween party (2016) at my house. I have a long driveway (about 500 feet), and I'm trying to place small speakers, to play music through all them as people walk up the driveway. Since this is outside where there is no power, that would also need to be taken into consideration. So like battery powered, passive speakers with one amp close to the house, or something else that I don't know of.

Does anyone have suggestions on what I'd be able to do? Also Can this be done on a $500 budget? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried searching for weatherproof speakers?